# Syntax Highlighting Color of HereDoc in Shell Language

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I need some help modifying the default syntax colors. I've already spent too much time trying to research how to change the following shell script default, please help me... ;-(

[Here's the way I don't like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD3cG.png)
[image]

[Here's how I would prefer it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI5hV.png)

[image]

Is there any hope of setting this up? I'm not color blind, but the red/blue just isn't friendly to my aging eyes. As you can see from the pictures, the issue is in the context of a variable tagged delimiter (or Operator?) as follows:

```
 {program}   <<{variable}
       code... 
       more code...
       even more...
  {variable}
```

Any help would be terrific!

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: Shell scripting with inline SQL code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is that language **Languages** > **Shell** (for **sh** extension) is in **Style Configurator** presented as **bash** what can be misleading (and it was misleading for me), but it is really the same language. And inside its styles, you can control a style called **`HERE Q`** to achieve what you need.

See the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That default formatting is horrible. The formatting made me rewrite my bash scripts another way.. lol